# Копия переменной не изменяется, изменяется только ее оригинальный список (Python)

Tags: python, list

Извините за странный заголовок, я не знаю как еще можно это объяснить. У меня уже голова болит от этой странной ошибки.

Итак, допустим у нас есть список:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

И я хочу сделать копию списка чтобы ее потом изменить:

```
list2 = list1
```

И теперь. Когда список скопирован. Я хочу удалить элемент, но вот одна не задача:

```
list2.remove("a")
# Но при этом, элемент удаляется не у list2, а у list1
```

Comment: Это не копия, это ссылка. Копия вот: `list2 = list1.copy()`. А вообще этот вопрос 100500 раз тут обсуждался, найдут дубликат - закроют.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Копирование списка делается неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507014/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: @Volk по-моему в том вопросе слишком много нерелевантного кода

Comment: @CrazyElf извините, но я гуглил много раз, и не находил таких вопросов. Всё же спасибо вам!

Comment: @Vagif Да я не с претензией, я просто предсказал неизбежные будущие события, уже произошедшие, кстати )

Comment: @Vagif, там есть и код, но! В том вопросе есть нужный вам запрос и ниже в ответе четко расписано, почему так.